# SAML is a first class citizen in SharePoint 2016, does that mean it doesn't require ADFS for authentication?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, saml, sharepoint-2016

SAML is a first class citizen in SharePoint 2016, does that mean it doesn't require ADFS for authentication?

I am configuring SharePoint 2016 for the first time and trying to determine if a need and AD FS Server to perform authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ADFS, however, you may need to develop your own people picker.